# Unable to match part of the word

Tags: java, regex

I have written a program to copy the 1st line which is containing the matching word, words or part of the word or words. I got the result for word or words by using the following code. When I enter the part of the word I’m getting the null value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String paragraph="First time in a long time the cricket team is in Kandy and there is no rain and the skies are blue. Strange days. Hope it stays that way";
        String searchWord="lo";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][^.?!]*?)?(?<!\\w)(?i)(" + searchWord + ")(?!\\w)[^.?!]*?[.?!]{1,2}\"?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(paragraph);
        String sentence = null;
        while (m.find()) {
              sentence = m.group();
              break;
        }
        System.out.println(sentence);
  }
```

Please suggest me how can I search part of the word?

Comment: Possibly you could just use contains rather than your regex? What are you trying to achieve with it? There seem to be more requirements here.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you must got a empty match as output because the substring `lo` is followed by a word character `n` in the string `long`. So change the negative lookahead `(?!\\w)` to positive lookahead `(?=\\w)` in your regex in-order to get a match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][^.?!]*?)?(?<!\\w)(?i)(" + searchWord + ")(?=\\w)[^.?!]*?[.?!]{1,2}\"?");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/7)

```
String paragraph="First time in a long time the cricket team is in Kandy and there is no rain and the skies are blue. Strange days. Hope it stays that way";
String searchWord="lo";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][^.?!]*?)?(?<!\\w)(?i)(" + searchWord + ")(?=\\w)[^.?!]*?[.?!]{1,2}\"?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(paragraph);
String sentence = null;
while (m.find()) {
      sentence = m.group();
      break;
}
System.out.println(sentence);
```

**Output:**

```
First time in a long time the cricket team is in Kandy and there is no rain and the skies are blue.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex in this case. You can make it simple bu using `String.split()` method.

Just split based on dot and find the characters in each sentence to get the desired sentence.

Sample code:

```
String paragraph = "First time in a long time the cricket team is in Kandy and there is no rain and the skies are blue. Strange days. Hope it stays that way";
String searchWord = "lo";
String sentence = null;
for (String str : paragraph.split("\\.\\s*")) { 
    // split based on dot followed by zero or more whitespaces
    if (str.indexOf(searchWord) != -1) { 
        // or use if(str.contains(searchWord))
        sentence = str;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(sentence);
```